# what's the default encoding of the pyqt4 and how to change it

Tags: python, encoding, pyqt4

I'm learning pyqt4 in python3, but in the beginning it raise the UnicodeEncodeError like this:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 9-10: ordinal not in range(256)
```

**here is my code is:**

```
app=QtGui.QApplication( sys.argv )
```

if someone met this error before?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: Clearly the error message suggests that it is expecting Latin-1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that this error occurs just because I don't run it in a .py file, I just write the command in Ipython, so when I write one command, it just run it ,so that's wrong. It looks like so stupid.